# C++ HDF5 cannot find -lhdf5d

Tags: c++, qt, hdf5

**Situation:** I want to create a program to read something from a `.hdf5` file.

**What i did:** Nothing, but adding the `hdf5.lib` to the project.

**Problem:**

I get two Errors

[image]

when i try to run the program.

```
cannot find -lhdf5d
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**My Code:**

`HDF5_Test.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
     main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5d
else:unix: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#define H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T H5_SIZEOF_LONG_LONG //this is needed to avoid redefinition conflict of ssize_t (Qt vs HDF5)
#include <hdf5.h>
#include <H5Cpp.h> //Tried with and without this include

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Using:**

- C++
- Qt 5.10.1
- MinGW 32bit
- HDF5 1.10.2
- Windows 7

---

In another project for whatever reason these Errors doesn't occur, but these.

[image].

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4333

Comment: Thanks, but not really helped.

Comment: On Linux/macOS there is also a wrapper around the compiler `h5c++` which calls the compiler with correct linking. One way is also to checkout how it calls the compiler, and mimic the behaviour. The other suggestion is to use CMake, but I guess this is not really an option for you, as you want to use Qt's build system, because it is a nightmare to link Qt otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was for me to delete the final "d" in this line:

```
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5d
```

Meaning i changed `-lhdf5d` to `-lhdf5`.

[This problem was fixed this way  but lead to another problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020354/how-to-add-an-external-library-to-a-qt-project-for-newbies)

Answer (score 0):

I linux, using apt-get install libhdf5-dev we get 8 libs installed but none is lihdf5 in its "nature". What i mean by that is that my include would be `-lhdf5_openmpi` and not`-lhdf5`. as you didn't provide the download source, try to check if you have multiple libs in your `/lib` file